# OnceAsync - explanation

Tags: firebase, xamarin

On my first trip to Xamarin (for a simple Android application) I add saving results in Firebase. I found an example of how to do and use it. In one of the lines, I can see OnceAsync. The search for an explanation wasn't successful. Where can I find what it means (and also PostAsync)?

Example:

```
public async Task<Person> GetPerson(string ime)
        {
            var allPersons = await GetAllPersons();
            await firebase
              .Child("Persons")
              .OnceAsync<Person>();
            return allPersons.Where(a => a.Ime == ime).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Firebase supports background retries and by using `Once` you are saying, only try this API call once and not repeat it later if a failure occurs.

re: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries

> Cloud Functions guarantees at-least-once execution of a background function for each event emitted by an event source. However, by default, if a function invocation terminates with an error, the function will not be invoked again, and the event will be dropped. When you enable retries on a background function, Cloud Functions will retry a failed function invocation until it completes successfully, or the retry window (by default, 7 days) expires.